# chrome cannot run console.log() Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, console.log

That is my html code

```
     <body>
        <script src="../js/myjscode.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is myjscode.js

```
     function firstFunction() {
            console.log("
        hello world ");
    }

    firstFunction();
```

if I type `console.log("hello world ");` on `myjscode.js`

is perfect output `hello world`

but if I type

```
function firstFunction() {
        console.log("
    hello world ");
}

firstFunction();
```

on myjscode.js

it show on chrome console 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

what wrong did I got?

Comment: keep this in single line `        console.log("
    hello world ");` no wrapping

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is a new line carriage return when you type the string in the new line inside the `console.log()` and due to that you get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. To resolve that use a backquote instead of quotes:

```js
function firstFunction() {
  console.log(`
  hello world`);
}

firstFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the console.log text in one line on your example.

Like this:

```
function firstFunction() {
        console.log("hello world");
}

firstFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an *escape sequence* to indicate a line break within a string; in your case,

```
"\nhello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either A: put the console.log in the same line, or B: turn it into a button. or do both!

## Javascript

```
function firstFunction() {
     console.log("hello world");
}
firstFunction();
```

## HTML

```
<button onclick="firstFunction()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do multi-line (like you do since you do linebreak after the quote) you must concatenate.

This works:

```
console.log("" +
    "hello world "
);
```

or

```
console.log(
 "hello world"
);
```

or:

```
console.log(
     "hello" +
      "world"
);
```